# OpenGL - how to check a default framebuffer color encoding

Tags: opengl, glfw

I have created an OpenGL application using GLFW library. The default framebuffer supports SRGB:
`glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SRGB_CAPABLE, 1);`

After calling `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)` I get a desired result on the screen when render a test texture.

Out of curiosity I have called `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv` for the default framebuffer:

```
GLint encoding = 0;
glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_BACK_LEFT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING, &encoding);
```

The encoding variable equals GL_LINEAR (also for GL_FRONT_LEFT buffer). [The documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter.xhtml) says that:

> For a default framebuffer, color encoding is determined by the
> implementation.

but I have set SRGB encoding explicitly during window creation so the encoding variable should be equal to GL_SRGB. Could you explain how does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your system support the extensions like [EXT_framebuffer_sRGB](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB.txt) or [ARB_framebuffer_sRGB](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_framebuffer_sRGB.txt)?

You will need this for the sRGB default framebuffer.